Which Mesopotamian gods had sacred numbers?
In ancient Mesopotamian cuneiform, there were a few different ways of writing a deity's name. You could spell it out, you could write one of their divine purviews, or you could use a "sacred number". If you wanted to talk about the sun-god Shamash, for example, you could spell out his name šá-maš, you could write the sign UTU "sun", or you could write the number 20.
Which deities had these sacred numbers, and how were they assigned? A couple of them make sense to me—30 for the moon-god, since it takes about a month for the moon to go through its phases—but most of them seem very arbitrary.

Related, though I find the answers there a bit dubious and they don't cite any sources.

To start things off, here are the ones I know of, taken from here:

10 for Adad, god of storms and power
15 for Ishtar, goddess of love and war
20 for Shamash, god of the sun and justice
30 for Sîn, god of the moon and fertility
40 or 60 for Ea, god of magic and water
50 for Enlil, god of authority
60 for Anu, god of the sky and kingship; this could also be read as 1, thanks to their place value system
3600 for Anshar and Kishar, primordial heaven and earth, but this sign should probably be read as "everything" instead of as "3600"

I don't know when or why these were used, though.
